# Can any one explain this code for Ceaser Cipher

Tags: shell-script, tr

```
IN="MJHVIZN ZPIO YJHPN"

for I in $(seq 25); do
    echo $I $IN | tr $(printf %${I}s | tr ' ' '.')\A-Z A-ZA-Z
done
```

Can Any one explain this code. I am confused with this nested statement

`echo $I $IN | tr $(printf %${I}s | tr ' ' '.')\A-Z A-ZA-Z`

Answer (score 2):

I put an echo in to it, so that I could see what the 2nd command in the pipeline is. The arguments to this command are constructed with `$()`.

```
in="MJHVIZN ZPIO YJHPN"

for i in $(seq 25); do
    echo tr $(printf %${i}s | tr ' ' '.')\A-Z A-ZA-Z
done
```

After running it should make more sense.

Also removed the capitals in variable names. I don't know who is teaching there use. There is a standard that says they should be lower-case.

Comment: I have executed that and know how it works. What I want to know is what is the output of $(printf %${I}s | tr ' ' '.') to be specific. How is it altering the string and the output. I want t know logic behind that

Comment: That is exactly why I added echo. You can see what the output of `printf` is. Do you understand what `$(...)` does?

Comment: Thanks... got it now:)

Answer (score 2):

In `printf`, `%[number]s` prints a string to a fixed-length field *number* characters wide, filling with space. So `%12s` produces a 12-character field, or just 12 spaces if the string is empty, like it is here. So `printf %${I}s` produces as many spaces as the variable `I` tells, they're then changed to dots.

So, if `I` is, say `4`, the other `tr` gets a first argument of `....A-Z`, and a second of `A-ZA-Z`. Expanding those and putting them next to each other we get

```
....ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

which corresponds to a four-character shift, as much as the value of `I` was.